# how to pass search key and get result through bs4

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

```
def get_main_page_url("https://malwr.com/analysis/search/", strDestPath, strMD5):

    base_url = 'https://malwr.com/'
    url = 'https://malwr.com/account/login/'

    username = 'myname'
    password = 'pswd'

    session = requests.Session()

    # getting csrf value
    response = session.get(url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.content)
    form = soup.form
    csrf = form.find('input', attrs={'name': 'csrfmiddlewaretoken'}).get('value')
##    csrf1 = form.find('input', attrs ={'name': 'search'}).get('value')

    # logging in
    data = {
        'username': username,
        'password': password,
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf
    }

    session.post(url, data=data)

    # getting analysis data
    response = session.get(urlparameter)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.content)
    form = soup.form
    csrf = form.find('input', attrs={'name': 'csrfmiddlewaretoken'}).get('value')
##    csrf1 = form.find('input', attrs ={'name': 'search'}).get('value')

    data = {
        'search': strMD5,
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf
    }

    session.post(urlparameter, data = data)
    response = session.get(urlparameter)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.content)
    print(soup)
    if(None != soup.find('section', id='file').find('table')('tr')[-1].a):
        link = soup.find('section', id='file').find('table')('tr')[-1].a.get('href')
        link = urljoin(base_url, link)

        webFile = session.get(link)
        filename =link.split('/')[-2]
        filename = arg + filename
        localFile = open(filename, 'wb')
        localFile.write(webFile.content)
        webFile.close()
        localFile.close()
```

I am able to login by searching `crftoken`. Then I am trying to send `MD5` to search on `malware.com`, however I am not able to get the page that searches the sent MD5 to page.

I want to search the MD5 that we passes through `crftoken`.
Please let me know what is the wrong in code.

Comment: @ http://stackoverflow.com/users/771848/alecxe  is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've done almost everything correctly. Except that you need to pass the result of the `POST` request to `BeautifulSoup`. Replace:

```
session.post(urlparameter, data = data)
response = session.get(urlparameter)
```

with:

```
response = session.post(urlparameter, data=data)
```

Worked for me (I had an account at malwr).

Comment: I want to search MD5 on this site also https://www.hybrid-analysis.com/search/ , however there is no such crftoken to search and pass as data  to url while posting.

Comment: @martin could you please make a separate question out of it? Thanks.